# Finding General Formulas for $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\cos(x)}$ and $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\sin(x)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Hello Math Stack Exchange Community,

I have a quick question:

How would I find the general formulas for $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\cos(x)}\, dx$ and $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a+b\sin(x)} \, dx$ using complex analysis?

I know I would need to use that $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$ and that $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$, but that's where I get lost. I don't understand quite how to do this. Please help me if you can, Math Stack Exchange Community. I have been trying to understand this concept for a good amount of time.

Comment: Next you need to make the change of variable $z := e^{ix}$, so that the integrals transform into contour integrals along the unit circle over the complex plane.

Comment: Aren't they equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that $a>b>0$ and enforce the substitution $z=e^{ix}$ and proceed using contour integration.
Thus, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{a+b\cos(x)}\,dx&=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{a+b\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)}\,\frac{1}{iz}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac1i\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{az+bz^2/2+b/2}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac2{ib}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z^2+2(a/b)z+1}\\\\
&=\frac2{ib}\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{\left(z+(a/b)+\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1}\right)\left(z+(a/b)-\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1}\right)}\,dz\tag1 \\\\
&=2\pi i (2i/b) /\left(2\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1}\right)\tag 2\\\\
&=2\pi/\sqrt{a^2-b^2}
\end{align}$$

where we applied the residue theorem in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$.  Note that the only pole inside $|z|=1$ is at $z=-(a/b)+\sqrt{(a/b)^2-1}$

Comment: I think this is a pretty good answer. I think maybe seeing this worked out with an example may be beneficial. I am a little bit confused with this as I don't think I have a strong foundation of Complex Analysis, but I think this should work for cosine. I don't know what I would need to do for sine. 

Also, on a side note, I do not know how to tag you here. I think markviola should work but we will see.

Furthermore, I do have one question: why do we have $|z|=1$?

Comment: @SidMeka Pleased to hear that the answer was useful.  To address some of the questions ... For the case of the sine function, use $$\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e(-ix}{2i}=\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}$$ and proceed analogously.  And since on the unit circle, $z=e^{ix}$, and hence $|z|=1$.  Aside, markviola is my username and should work with the "@" sign placed before it.

Comment: I tried to upvote, but apparently, I do not have enough reputation. @MarkViola

Comment: Also, quick question: Wouldn't $$\cos(x) = \frac{(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{2}$$

Comment: @SidMeka Indeed.  It is true that $\cos(x)=\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$. And in fact,  this was used in the development.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thanks for the help.

-- Sid

Comment: Thank you.  And you're welcome.   It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $t=\tan(\tfrac x2)$. Then
$$4\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{t^2+\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$$

Comment: The OP states "... using complex analysis? And the tags are $(1)$ complex analysis and $(2)$ contour integration.

Comment: @MarkViola I didnt notice that day. Half tangent substitution is cool. İ hope I dont get downvote.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Here is an alternative approach to compare with.

I would recommend you to notice that:

\begin{align*}
\cos(2x) = \frac{\cos^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x)}{\cos^{2}(x) + \sin^{2}(x)} = \frac{1 - \tan^{2}(x)}{1 + \tan^{2}(x)}
\end{align*}

Hence you can obtain the first primitive by making the change of variable $x = 2\arctan(t)$.

Similarly, one has that:
\begin{align*}
\sin(2x) = \frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^{2}(x) + \sin^{2}(x)} = \frac{2\tan(x)}{1 + \tan^{2}(x)}
\end{align*}

From now on, I think you can handle the proposed exercise.

Comment: The OP states "... using complex analysis? And the tags are $(1)$ complex analysis and $(2)$ contour integration.