# Is $\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\frac{dx}{1-k^2\sin^2x}$ an elliptic integral?

Tags: trigonometric-integrals, elliptic-integrals

Let $\Delta=\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}$, $E(k)=\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\Delta dx$ and $K(k)=\int\frac{dx}{\Delta}.$

[Start wearing purple,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/427738/221315) gives a nice answer for the interesting identity $\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\frac{dx}{\Delta^3}=\frac{E(k)}{1-k^2}.$

It is stuck in my head: Is $\int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\frac{dx}{\Delta^2}$ an elliptic integral?
If so or not, can it be represented in terms of $k, E(k), K(k)$?

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $t=\tan x$?

Comment: @J.G. I tried $\tan\frac x2$. But it is complicated. I am not sure about the final result.

Comment: [Bioche's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules) favour my alternative.

Comment: This is a standard result, not related to elliptic integrals.
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\Delta^2}dx=\frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}$$

Comment: It is a standard result @BobDobbs as user @ Miracle Invoker has pointed.

Comment: @User I know. See my answer here. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4825488/221315

Answer (score 0):

By the standard substution $\sin x=y, dx =du/\sqrt{1-u^2}$ yields the integral

$$\int   \frac{du}{\sqrt{(1-u)(1+u)(1-k u)^2(1+k u)^2)}}$$

that is not an elliptic integral by the definition, the polynomial to be of degree 4 at most. So by complex topology, it cannot be expressed by elliptic integrals, just by the different structure of the Riemann surfaces.

The indefinite integral is trival  of  a form $\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-k^2} \tan (x)\right)}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}$, whose inversion is not doubly periodic in the complex domain, the  central property of elliptic functions. That happens for elliptic integrals for the special cases $k=0, k=1$ only.

The reason of algebraic triviality is the fact, that the denominator has the simple trigonometric form

$$ \int \frac{dx}{a + b \cos(2x)}$$

Comment: Wikipedia says "... of degree 3 or 4" somewhere in the definition. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

Comment: Yes, but the standard projection for elliptic integrands  onto the real line here yields degree 6, with 6 possible branch points . But that is topologically not true, instead the integrand has an infinity of simple poles at   $a+\cos(2x) =0$.

Comment: I didnt understand your answer. :(